# ggts-3.6.3 vanishes after entering project name on projectCreation

Tags: grails, ggts

it us strongly recommended to upgrade to ggts-3.6.3. I tried to do so and installed
     groovy-grails-tool-suite-3.6.3.RELEASE-e4.4.1-linux-gtk-x86_64.tar.gz
When I try to create a project via new, project, after entering the projectName ggts-3.6.3 vanishes from the screen without any message.

peter

Comment: addInfo: I'm using ubuntu 14.4

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem after upgrading from 3.6.1 to 3.6.3, so I reverted back to 3.6.1. You can download 3.6.1 [here](http://download.springsource.com/release/STS/3.6.1/dist/e4.4/groovy-grails-tool-suite-3.6.1.RELEASE-e4.4-linux-gtk-x86_64.tar.gz).